# How to enable CORS policy in AWS between API Gateway and React app?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cors

I want to send an email through lambda function on AWS. I also used API gateway. I enable cors there and send headers with lambda function and in react app too.

Lambda Function

```
var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
   };
```

My React APP

```
const awsEndpoint = 'myawsendpoint.amazonaws.com'
axios.post(awsEndpoint, {
 headers: {
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 },
 formEmail,
 formSubject,
 formMessage

})
```

In the console Im getting below error
[chrome-console-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9BnP.jpg)

Comment: What is your configuration for api gateway to allow cors?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api- Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'                                                                            
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'

Comment: I'm wondering if its an issue with hitting from localhost. You may want to try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`: `http://localhost:3000`  in api gateway

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: The https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9BnP.jpg screenshot shows that the server is responding with a 403 error to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request. So you need to add additional handling to the server-side code for the server you’re sending the request to — you need to make the server respond to all OPTIONS requests (evn unauthenticated requests) with a 200 OK and the right CORS response headers. The server needs to send back an Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type header and an Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST header.

Comment: Remove the part of your frontend React code that’s trying to set the Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. Those headers are not request headers. They are response headers. You can’t set those headers in your frontend code. Instead, they must be sent back as response headers by the server to which the request is made.

Comment: I followed this article btw https://linuxacademy.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-build-a-serverless-contact-form-on-aws/  - My function looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

to solve this issue you need to update your CORS policy (for each route, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, etc) in the AWS API Gateway console. I would read this great Medium article that has screenshots and a detailed explanation of cors

Solution: https://codeburst.io/react-js-api-calls-to-aws-lambda-api-gateway-and-dealing-with-cors-89fb897eb04d

Comment: Thank you for that, it works now! Sometimes you get lost in a problem even if the solution is right in front of you. You just didn't take the time to really get all settings right, which is pretty well explained in this article.

Comment: I cant implement it while I enable my proxy integration

Comment: The article is behind a paywall, it would be nice to summarise it here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a small lambda function and integrating it to an OPTIONS method at the "/{proxy+}" path. Instructions below, best of luck!

1. Create simple lambda function to return 200 for an OPTIONS method request. I did so applying same role of the lambda function that has the CORS issue. AWS code example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZl6Y.png)

I used the python hello-world template and dropped this in:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
        },
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

2. Create OPTIONS method for "/{proxy+}" path in your api gateway

[image]

3. Select integrations on the left pane and attach your new simple 200 response lambda function as an integration for the OPTIONS method

[image]

That got me up and running. I figure you can tighten down the restrictions once you know it's working. Below is a screenshot of my CORS settings when I initially got mine working as well:

[image]

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a proxy in your package.json? This will allow you to access your AWS gateway from localhost.

in your `package.json`

```json
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "proxy": "myawsendpoint.amazonaws.com",
    ....
```

then you can use a partial path to access your resource

```js
fetch("/your-resource", options)
```